# BeagleBone Black: UART crashes the BBB after two successful read write calls

Tags: c, beagleboneblack, uart

I'm having some trouble getting consistent UART with the BBB. I've set things up as shown on [this page](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-Programming-HOWTO/x115.html) for non-canonical inputs. I seem to be able to transmit just fine, even on the third cycle. It's the read command that seems to be getting me. I'm not even really sure where to start with this so any pointers would be greatly appreciated! Here's the code I'm using:

EDIT: For specificity

When I say two read and write calls I mean my loop executes as expected twice. I send out the data and read exactly what I expected to. On the third attempt at reading, after the "wrote data..." printf executes, the program crashes. I can still CTRL-C out and run the BBB as usual, and restarting the program will let me read and write exactly twice again before the same issue arises.

With the while loop condition, I accidentally forgot to add the initialization of the read_test variable in the code you see below. I'm adding this serial communication to a much larger program controlling a robot I do research on. I believe I've captured all of the relevant code, this test is the first thing that happens after I initialize all the variables I need, however if the entire file is helpful I can add it.

```
void SERIAL_Init(void)
{
/*******************************************************************/
  printf("\tSerial Port Initialization ...");
    SERIAL_fd = open(MODEMDEVICE,O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY /*| O_NDELAY*/);
  if (SERIAL_fd < 0)
    { perror(MODEMDEVICE);
      exit(-1);
    }
  fcntl(SERIAL_fd,F_SETFL,0);
  tcgetattr(SERIAL_fd,&newtio);
  newtio.c_cflag |=  CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD ;
  cfsetispeed(&newtio,BAUDRATE);
  cfsetospeed(&newtio,BAUDRATE);
  newtio.c_iflag = IGNBRK | IGNPAR;
  newtio.c_oflag = 0;
  newtio.c_lflag = 0;
  newtio.c_cc[VTIME]=0;             /* inter-character timer unused */
  newtio.c_cc[VMIN]=31;             /* blocking read until 18 chars received */
  tcflush(SERIAL_fd,TCIFLUSH);
  tcsetattr(SERIAL_fd,TCSANOW,&newtio);
  /****************************************************************/
  printf("Done\n");
  return;
}

//Test data for reading serial
    unsigned char test_data[2] = {0x00,0x00};

//Read from maestro command
    unsigned char read_command[2][2] = {
        {0x1a,0x2b},
        {0x90,0x05},
    };

while(readTest == 0)
    {
        printf("Enter 0 to read from maestro pin, 1 to continue with testing\n");
        scanf("%d",&readTest);

        write(SERIAL_fd,read_command[0],2);
        printf("Wrote values...\n");
        num_bytes = read(SERIAL_fd,&test_data,2);
        printf("Value read: %x %x\n",test_data[0],test_data[1]);

    }
```

Comment: Please be more specific about what your probelm is.

Comment: To be clear: when you say 'two successful read write calls', you mean that the read calls returned the expected data and that 'num_bytes' was returned as 2 each time?

Comment: But how can it even perform two iterations with this `while` condition?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific on what exactly crashes? The whole Beagle? Linux? Your program?

Comment: Thanks for the responses everyone, I've edited the main question to hopefully clarify my issues.

Comment: Your code has VTIME=0, VMIN=31, but a read requests only 2 bytes.  That's considered "undefined behaviour".  Study http://unixwiz.net/techtips/termios-vmin-vtime.html, especially the last paragraph & sentence.  The proper values that you should use would depend on the data that you expect to receive and read.  BTW as with most OSes, your program does not "read" directly from the UART; it's fetching data from system buffers.  IOW your title is incorrect, and the UART and its driver are not involved at all.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved by changing to VMIN=2 to match the amount of data I'm expecting with each read command. Reading this page was incredibly helpful. I thought having the VMIN set high wasn't the problem since I was still getting for the first two commands even though the number of bytes was below the old VMIN value, however that makes sense now given "We believe that it's undefined behavior if nbytes is less then VMIN." Thanks so much for the help!